# Stored procedure OUTPUT string result is only one char instead of full string

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sqlcommand

I have some problem with this code, the return variable I want is "Sơn" instead of 'S'

My code:

```
SentoDB.RunProcedure("usp_GetNameWithIdCategory");
SqlParameter CategoryID = new SqlParameter("CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int);
CategoryID.Value = Int32.Parse(item.Value);
SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter("result", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
result.Value = string.Empty;
SentoDB.AddParameters(CategoryID);
SentoDB.AddParameters(result);
SentoDB.LoadProcedure();
```

The variable result.Value.ToString() is 'S' Instead of "Sơn"

```
public void RunProcedure(string procedureName)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connect);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
}

public void LoadProcedure()
{
    connect.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connect.Close();
}
```

Stored procedure in SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetNameWithIdCategory 
     (@CategoryID INT, @result NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = Cate.Name 
    FROM Category AS Cate 
    WHERE Cate.CategoryID = @CategoryID
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a size to the parameter.
I had the same issue with varbinary until added the size.

Comment: You mean `SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter("result", SqlDbType.NVarChar);` in this line.

Comment: true, there's an implementation with the size argument